# How correct orginize work with frontend and backend in spring boot app?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

People, hello everyone. Of course, quite a noob question, but ... In general, the front makes a familiar one, I do the back on the spring with thymeleaf connected. As a result, he throws off his html files to me, I already include styles in them using thymeleaf, etc., i.e. I change pieces of his code to my own. But suppose you need to change something in the layout, it turns out that he needs to delete all my timelif tags, and re-connect all his styles to make changes, and again through the cycle? How to organize such work in general?

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf uses natural templates, which means you can have HTML that can be viewed as a static page for design purpose and will still work fine when Thymeleaf kicks in when the application is run.

As an example, you can refer to your CSS for example like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}" href="../../../static/css/styles.css">
```

When you look at this page as a simple static page, then `href` is active. When the page is rendered by Thymeleaf, then `th:href` becomes active.

You can also take a look at https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html to see how `th:remove` is used to remove certain tags from the HTML when Thymeleaf is active, but can be used for static styling.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. With the help of thymeleaf I have added snippets to the page like footer, head etc. The person who develops the frontend does not see these fragments until the application is running. The question is how to properly organize the development of the front and back? Should they run in parallel? And if so, how?

Comment: If you are using Thymeleaf, developers usually work on both back and frontend. This allows to deliver a complete feature, avoiding that only the backend or only the frontend is done. If you have currently such a divide in the team, maybe some training is needed for team members to learn about "the other half".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The front-end person has no idea, thymeleaf tags and functionality. What would be the right thing to do?